# 1 interaction, 2 different marginal effects plots (generalized additive mixed model)

Tags: interaction, mgcv

I have a question regarding the proper syntax for including an interaction in mgcv. It was my understanding that a continuous*factor interaction can be included in a generalized additive model like this (below) and that these are very similar models (one being the linear version of the other). However, while trying to decide if the interaction term is needed, I noticed that they produce very different marginal effect plots. Why might the relationship between my factor (fZone) and my continuous covariate (SL) change directions between these two versions of (what I thought to be) close to the same model?

This is related to my OP [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/617315/how-to-determine-if-an-interaction-is-warranted-in-a-generalized-additive-mixed). Judging from the plot, I see why the interaction term in my "smooth_inter_mod" wouldn't be necessary, but AIC and BIC are both better for the "para_mod". I may have therefore concluded the interaction term was capturing something important. Sorry for the posting of related questions! I'm not expecting a fast answer, just very surprised!

```
library(mgcv)
library(ggeffects)   

para_mod <- bam(empty ~
                      SL*fZone +
                      
                      s(sal) + 
                      s(temp) + 
                      s(ToD) + 
                      
                      # Structural component
                      s(fStation, bs = "re") +         
                      s(fCYR, bs = "re") +            
                      s(fStation, fCYR, bs = "re") +   
                      s(fStation, CYR.std, bs = "re"), 
                    
                    data = c_neb5, 
                    method = 'fREML', 
                    discrete = TRUE, # speed benefit
                    family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
                    select = TRUE,
                    gamma = 1.3)

smooth_inter_mod <- bam(empty ~
                      s(SL) + 
                      fZone + 
                      s(SL, by=fZone, m=1) + 
                      
                      s(sal) + 
                      s(temp) + 
                      s(ToD) + 
                      
                      # Structural component
                      s(fStation, bs = "re") +         
                      s(fCYR, bs = "re") +            
                      s(fStation, fCYR, bs = "re") +   
                      s(fStation, CYR.std, bs = "re"), 
                    
                    data = c_neb5, 
                    method = 'fREML', 
                    discrete = TRUE, # speed benefit
                    family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
                    select = TRUE,
                    gamma = 1.3) 

> AIC(para_mod, smooth_inter_mod)
                       df      AIC
para_mod         25.01311 717.7365
smooth_inter_mod 27.20705 722.3590    

> BIC(para_mod, smooth_inter_mod)
                       df      BIC
para_mod         25.01311 830.8114
smooth_inter_mod 27.20705 845.3517
```

Plots:

```
ggpredict(para_mod, c("SL", "fZone")) %>% plot()
```

[image]

```
ggpredict(smooth_inter_mod, c("SL", "fZone")) %>% plot()
```

[image]

Data:

```
> example_data <- c_neb5[sample(nrow(c_neb5), 10), ]

> dput(example_data)
structure(list(CYR_Keyfield = c("C-2018-9-15-240", "C-2016-8-14-172", 
"C-2018-10-8-176", "C-2017-8-13-70", "C-2010-7-31-159", "C-2012-8-12-68", 
"C-2018-8-21-279", "C-2017-8-15-237", "C-2019-6-25-240", "C-2019-5-16-254"
), Species = c("Cynoscion nebulosus", "Cynoscion nebulosus", 
"Cynoscion nebulosus", "Cynoscion nebulosus", "Cynoscion nebulosus", 
"Cynoscion nebulosus", "Cynoscion nebulosus", "Cynoscion nebulosus", 
"Cynoscion nebulosus", "Cynoscion nebulosus"), ID = c("20189240_54", 
"20168172_42", "201810176_58", "2017870_66", "20107159_1", "2012868_1", 
"20188279_126", "20178237_35", "20196240_114", "20195254_11"), 
    SL = c(29.77, 28.9, 29.97, 24.74, 33.16, 64.96, 52.18, 31.03, 
    26.46, 15.63), empty = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), DateTime = structure(c(1537029540, 
    1471181160, 1539009840, 1502636160, 1280597280, 1344789960, 
    1534864020, 1502801520, 1561476120, 1558012140), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), CYR = c(2018L, 2016L, 2018L, 2017L, 
    2010L, 2012L, 2018L, 2017L, 2019L, 2019L), Month = c(9L, 
    8L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 5L), DoY = c(258, 227, 281, 
    225, 212, 225, 233, 227, 176, 136), ToD = c(12.65, 9.43333333333333, 
    10.7333333333333, 10.9333333333333, 13.4666666666667, 12.7666666666667, 
    11.1166666666667, 8.86666666666667, 11.3666666666667, 9.15
    ), JDay = c(5108, 4346, 5131, 4710, 2140, 2883, 5083, 4712, 
    5391, 5351), Zone = c("Rankin", "West", "West", "West", "West", 
    "West", "Rankin", "Rankin", "Rankin", "Rankin"), Station = c(240, 
    172, 176, 70, 159, 68, 279, 237, 240, 254), Standard_collection_station = c(0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Latitude = c(25.088, 25.104, 
    25.1, 25.132, 25.07, 25.121, 25.133, 25.126, 25.088, 25.098
    ), Longitude = c(-80.828, -80.891, -80.866, -80.941, -80.907, 
    -80.955, -80.797, -80.863, -80.828, -80.814), sal = c(37.22, 
    41.15, 36.4099999999999, 43.3, 43.5, 39.6, 34.6, 43, 37.61, 
    37.51), temp = c(32.3459999999998, 28.82, 25.5859999999998, 
    31.05, 34.5, 30.4, 31.1679999999999, 31.4, 33.75, 28.64), 
    fCYR = structure(c(9L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 10L
    ), levels = c("2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2015", 
    "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2021", "2022"), class = "factor"), 
    fMonth = structure(c(7L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 
    3L), levels = c("1", "3", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", 
    "11", "12"), class = "factor"), fStation = structure(c(56L, 
    44L, 48L, 11L, 39L, 10L, 70L, 54L, 56L, 59L), levels = c("20", 
    "21", "22", "23", "24", "40", "54", "65", "67", "68", "70", 
    "71", "73", "101", "105", "106", "107", "111", "112", "117", 
    "118", "119", "122", "123", "124", "130", "133", "134", "135", 
    "137", "143", "144", "145", "146", "147", "156", "157", "158", 
    "159", "167", "168", "169", "171", "172", "173", "174", "175", 
    "176", "224", "225", "226", "227", "229", "237", "239", "240", 
    "241", "253", "254", "255", "256", "257", "265", "266", "267", 
    "268", "269", "270", "278", "279", "280", "281", "282", "284", 
    "290", "291", "292", "294", "301", "302", "312", "609"), class = "factor"), 
    fZone = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), levels = c("Rankin", "West", "Whipray"), class = "factor"), 
    CYR.std = c(9L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 10L), center_sl = c(-10.5116053019146, 
    -11.3816053019146, -10.3116053019146, -15.5416053019146, 
    -7.12160530191458, 24.6783946980854, 11.8983946980854, -9.25160530191458, 
    -13.8216053019146, -24.6516053019146)), row.names = c(374L, 
316L, 393L, 432L, 67L, 55L, 584L, 277L, 618L, 91L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: A partial answer I received, hopefully it helps others! -- "The first plot forces the relationships to be linear on the scale of the link function, hence the monotonic relationships, the second with the smooths allows changes in direction. From the second plot, it almost looks like the interaction would not be significant anyway because of the huge overlap in error bars. It would be more surprising if the relationships were super tight and changed direction from one method to the other."